# OpenCV (any version) using SIFT in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I downloaded some code to perform a bag of words ML in python with opencv, numpy, scipy, sklearn.

It was OpenCV 3.0.0 I downloaded - I then realised that the code I had used 2 lines for sift keypoints:

*Create feature extraction and keypoint detector objects*

```
fea_det = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SIFT")                                
des_ext = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SIFT")
```

When trying to run the code through cmd I found it said this line had a problem, subsequently found opencv doesn't include sifts, and I needed to do opencv_contrib +cmake etc..
For the last 2 days I have been trying to compile the xfeatures2d file from contrib with the source of opencv 3.0 and it just doesnt work.

I have been looking at tons of documentation + stackoverflow questions but everytime I solve something there is a new problem. Last point I had everything built (102 built with 2 failed) but then the cv2.pyd file didn't include the new features. So it just didn't work, again.

I just want a simple solution that works, I am trying to learn machine learning, so could you please help me find:

a) in opencv 3.0 is there another close enough keypoint I could use? without having to compile opencv_contrib? (and what is the namespace? - I couldn't find any good python documentation for namespaces, just C++)

b) should I revert to another version e.g. 2.3 to use sift? if so what is the namespace please?

c) Thanks a lot for any help you can give, I can't tell you how disappointed I am that I still don't have this working after 2 days, all because of cmake. Amazing.

Thanks again!!

Fred

Comment: You can use akaze descriptors, or similar, in the features2d module. Anyhow, compiling contrib modules is pretty straightforward (at least C++ only, don't know for python). Revert to an older release is not a good idea, since some syntax changed in 3.0, and you'll be stuck to an old release in the future.

Comment: Okay. I also saw ORB in the 3.0 doc. I couldn't see any akaze for python but would it be something like:
fea_det = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("akaze")?

And for ORB:
cv2.orb.compute(??)

I'm looking at the documentation for this stuff but it is really not helping me at all.

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html

Thanks :)